# How to run an upstream task when a downstream task has been cleared?

Tags: airflow

I have a problem where a I need to run the parent even when a child task has been cleared. For eg: If I have `A->B->C->D->E->F`, if task `E` fails and it has been cleared by some one manually, then task `A` should also be cleared automatically. I am not sure whether there is any direct way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done via Airflow.
Airflow executes DAGs ( Directed Acyclic Graphs ), you cannot have this kind of pattern in a DAG.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have this type of pattern and you will get an exception

```
AirflowDagCycleException: Cycle detected in DAG
```

But how is about semi-automatic solution/workaround. Let's assume you have a DAG structure where task `F` is a downstream of both tasks `A` and `E`. i.e. [this is how your DAG will look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riwuq.png).

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F
A -> F
```

Now if task `F` fails, you need first **to pause DAG**, then clear task `A` [without recursion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wD473.png) and clear task `F` with recursion. In this case task `F` can't start running before both its' parents are in *success* state. Thus, task `A` will get triggered, but tasks `B - E` won't since you haven't cleared their state which was *success*.

Answer (score 0):

This can take place. There is an on_failure_callback parameter you can set at a task level. This function can be any code. In that function you could easily clear previous tasks and have them run again.